# In Azure stream analytics trying to pull a data from event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

In Azure stream analytics while trying to pull a data from event hub I am receiving the following error

> Diagnostics: Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind
> 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times
> '2020-11-19T04:08:35.3436931Z' and '2020-11-19T04:08:35.3686240Z'.
> Unable to create records from the given Avro record schema

I want to know what could be the reason?

Is there a way to find what kind of data file is streaming in EVENTHUB?

Answer (score 0):

Check the event serialization format of the input(your event hub). Potentially, what you set there, and what you are sending indeed does not match. Could be that you are sending JSON, but you specified AVRO as the event serialization or vice versa.

[image]

You can download [Service bus explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer), and connect it to your EventHub and that way inspect what you are getting. I advise adding an additional consumer group for your EventHub just to avoid competing consumers and connecting Service bus explorer to that particular consumer group.